# Как получить текст из div в js, если внутри div, есть теги span, с своим текстом?

Tags: javascript

```
Как получить div из тега в js, если внутри div, есть теги span, с своим текстом?

<div>
    <div class='qt'>
         <span class="text1">этот не нужно получать<span class="text2">и этот тоже</span></span> 
    А этот нужно получить. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Попытка:

```js
var $qtext = document.body.getElementsByClassName('qt');
var $question = $qtext[0].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
console.log("Текст " + $question[0].innerText);
```

```html
<div>
        <div class='qt'>
             <span class="text1">этот не нужно получать<span class="text2">и этот тоже</span></span> 
        А этот нужно получить. 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: подойдет? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6925135/6104996

Comment: Если чисто на js то `var qt = document.getElementsByClassName("qt")[0];
alert(qt.childNodes[2].textContent)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Большое спасибо. Тоже все работает. А вы часто пишите на js, или больше на JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно по-старинке оперировать узлами DOM. Например так:

```
var qt = document.querySelector('.qt'),
    children = qt.childNodes,
    value = children[children.length - 1].nodeValue.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');

console.log("Текст " + value);
```

А вот и рабочий [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/1xc89x34/2/) на JSFiddle.

Comment: Так выводит как у меня , весь текст https://jsfiddle.net/1xc89x34/1/

Comment: @gilo1212, врете. В консоль выводит `"Текст      \nА этот нужно получить. \n"`

Comment: А теперь еще и лишние пробельные символы по краям удаляет

Comment: Точно, вру! Спасибо, все отрабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант с проверкой [типа узла](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node)

```js
var $qtext = [].filter.call(document.querySelector('.qt').childNodes, node => node.nodeType == 3 && node.nodeValue.trim()).map(node => node.nodeValue.trim());
console.log($qtext.join('\n'));
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='qt'>
    <span class="text1">этот не нужно получать<span class="text2">и этот тоже</span></span>
    А этот нужно получить.
  </div>
</div>
```